# How can I close the newly opened Internet Explorer using the mshtml

Tags: microsoft.mshtml

I want to close a newly opened Internet Explorer using the mshtml.

I have a program , which takes values from different IE Window. The navigation to each Window is invoked using the Click() method of element. Once process the page,  I want to close the Window.

Any one know how to close the window using the Mshtml.

thanks in advance
Unni

Answer (score 1):

See the following code...

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
// IE can be found in COM library called 
// Microsoft Internet Controls: 
using IE = SHDocVw.InternetExplorer; 
static void OpenAndCloseIE()
{
    // Get an instance of Internet Explorer: 
    Type objClassType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("InternetExplorer.Application");
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(objClassType) as IE;

    // Close Internet Explorer again: 
    instance.Quit();

    // Release instance: 
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(instance);
    instance = null; // Don't forget to unreference it. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy: Get the `HWND` from `IWebBrowser2`, and send it a `WM_CLOSE`.